# E-mail verification needs to be done 2 times for self-service password reset in Azure Ad B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use self service password reset for my tenant in Azure AD B2C, but for some reason the verification of email needs to be done twice after you click on "Forgot your password?" link. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer for this question [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/392622/why-does-e-mail-verification-needs-to-be-done-2-ti.html).

Comment: MFA was set to 'conditional'. Changing it to off didn't work for me, I had to delete then re-create the flow for it to work